# "Ich komme um viertel vor sieben Uhr an." - doppelte Präposition?

Tags: preposition

Zeitangaben werden im Sprachgebrauch immer mit `um` eingeleitet: `um 07:00 Uhr` und auch `um viertel vor sieben (Uhr)`. Mein Logikverständnis findet das jedoch inkonsequent: entweder es ist **um** sieben oder irgendetwas **vor** sieben, aber niemals **um** irgendetwas **vor** sieben - die zwei Präpositionen statt einer machen mir zu schaffen. Weniger problematisch wird es natürlich bei der Form `um dreiviertel sieben`.

Gibt es zu diesen temporalen Adpositionen eine Regel, oder ist das `um` im Zweifel einfach optional? Auch erscheint mir das Substantiv `Uhr` nicht immer angebracht: `Ich komme um halb sieben Uhr an.` hab ich glaub ich noch nie gehört - hier wird doch auf das `Uhr` i.d.R. verzichtet.

Comment: "viertel vor sieben" ist "6:45 Uhr". Was ist daran kein Zeitpunkt, den man mit "um" nutzen kann?

Comment: Was ist denn mit "Ich komme um 5 nach sieben an" - Hast du damit auch ein Problem? Wenn ja, wie soll man das sonst sagen?

Comment: @IQV: das ist die Frage, ob beide Formen austauschbar sind, oder die eine `um ... Uhr` erzwingt und die andre weder `um` noch `Uhr`. @tofro: ja, ich würde sagen `Ich komme fünf nach sieben an.` oder wenn ich `um` verwenden will, dann halt `Ich komme um 07:05 Uhr an.`

Comment: So betrachtet hast du recht: man kann das "um" weglassen. Auch wenn es für mich etwas seltsam klingt.

Comment: Wie möchtest du den Ausdruck »Viertel vor sieben« denn sonst benutzen? Ohne Präposition? »Ich komme Viertel vor sieben an«?

Comment: @AmigoJack Und wie würdest du "07:05" aussprechen?

Comment: @Eller `Sieben Uhr fünf.` oder `Fünf nach sieben.` (wörtlich genommen = rein persönlich immer nur erstere Variante)

Comment: Um ist doppeldeutig, es kann auch 'gegen, etwa' bedeuten, also nicht `um Punkt sieben` sondern `um sieben herum`. `Ich komme viertel vor sieben an` geht m.E. auch. Das `um` muss man kunstvoll betonen, um zu unterstreichen, dass man `rund` meint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Das "um" gibt einen Zeitpunkt an. Es ist unabhängig davon, wie dieser Zeitpunkt sprachlich ausgedrückt wird.

Ob der Zeitpunkt jetzt "3 Uhr" oder "viertel vor 5" ist, ist egal. Die Formulierung ist immer

> Ich komme um [Zeitpunkt] an.

Daher sind diese Präpositionen eben auch getrennt zu betrachten. Du kannst das ja sogar noch weiter treiben:

> Ich komme nach viertel nach 8 an.

Und das ist eine völlig korrekte Zeitangabe.

Bezüglich des "Uhr": Man sagt auch nicht, es ist viertel vor 5 Uhr, sondern es ist viertel vor 5. Anders bei der Zeitangabe "Es ist 13 Uhr 15". Da wiederum sagt man nicht "Es ist 13 15" oder "Es ist 13 15 Uhr".

Comment: Und genauso wird nicht verwendet `Es ist um 13:15 Uhr.` - hier fehlt `um` trotz Zeitpunkts. Ich kann bei all diesen Varianten nicht mal ableiten, dass man entweder `um` oder `Uhr` verwenden sollte - wo ist die Logik?

Comment: @AmigoJack Vielleicht hat es etwas mit dem verwendeten Verb zu tun?

Comment: @IQV: hättest Du ein solches Gegenbeispiel? Ich komme/bin/mache/schließe/räume... mir fällt keins ein

Comment: @AmigoJack Dein Beispiel: Man sagt eben "Es ist 15 Uhr" und "Ich komme **um** 15 Uhr." Beim Ausdruck "Es ist..." wird kein "um" verwendet.

Comment: @AmigoJack Du verwechselst da zwei Dinge: Nur, dass "um" im Zusammenhang mit dem Verb "kommen" einen Zeitpunkt angibt, bedeutet nicht, dass bei jeder Angabe eines Zeitpunkts auch immer "um" verwendet werden muss.

Comment: Andere Beispiele: `Ich komme/Der Termin ist zu 15:00 Uhr`, `Der Zeitpunkt fällt auf 16:00 Uhr` - hier halte ich es für wahrscheinlicher, das `x Uhr` auch mit `viertel nach sieben` austauschen zu können - das spräche für die These, dass `um` in jedem Fall erlaubt ist.

Comment: Du hast aber verstanden, dass bestimmte Verben bestimmte Präpositionen erfordern? Beispielsweise kannst du nicht sagen, "Ich komme zu +Uhrzeit" oder "Der Termin ist zu +Uhrzeit".

Comment: Stimmt. Mein Logikverständnis hätte am liebsten `Ich komme viertel vor um sieben`, wohingegen phonetisch jede andere Variante besser klingt. Eure Beispiele und Erklärungen haben in jedem Fall geholfen.

Comment: Jetzt, einundzwanzig dreißig, muss ich doch widersprechen. Das sagt man schon. Wie auch 16 20 oder 23 55.

Comment: @userunknown Man sagt das *mal*, aber ich sehe das nicht als offiziellen Sprachgebrauch. Eine "normale" Zeitangabe wäre eben 16 Uhr 20 oder 23 Uhr 55.

Comment: Richtig, man sagt das nur selten, aber das macht es nicht zu unnormalem Sprachgebrauch. Offiziell - was mag das sein? Anschreiben im Behördendeutsch - überhaupt Schriftdeutsch, soweit es nicht wörtliche Rede wiedergibt. Ja. Aber dafür Klassenübergreifend. "Wann ist Feierabend, 16 Uhr?" "16 30". Ich wette man kann so den meisten eine Zeit nennen, ohne dass sie stutzen. Überall, wo viele Zeiten kommuniziert werden müssen bilden sich solche Kurzformeln. "Halb Fünf" sind natürlich weniger Silben, aber "16 20". Im ICE: "Wann  sind wir in Köln?" "17:53" (sprich: siebzehn dreiundfünfzig).

Comment: Jaja, aber wenn ich sag "zwanzig einundzwanzig" ist plötzlich nicht mehr klar, ob ich eine Uhrzeit oder das gregorianische Jahr meine. Wenn wir so argumentieren ist alles irgendwie richtig.